# Variable as Length in for Loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a problem with defining the length in my for loop.
I'm counting rows in a table from a SQL database and want this number to be the length of the for loop.

This is the code for the for loop:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
            new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv.ID = "createDiv";
            this.Controls.Add(createDiv);
        }

    }
```

And this is the code that counts the rows in my database table.

```
    public void A()
    {
        string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AlgSchipInfo";
        int count = 0;

        using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection ("DataSource=VMB-LP12;Initial Catalog=SmmsData;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
            {
                thisConnection.Open();
                count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
                TextBox2.Text = count.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to use this to show info on every ship that is in my database by creating divs in my for loop.

Can anyone help me with how I need to define the length?

Thanks!

Comment: Change `A` to return an `int`, have it return `count` and change your for loop to `i < A()` I guess?  `A` is a terrible name for a method, though.

Comment: Since you want to display info for every record. Then why wouldn't you just get the info and do a foreach?

Comment: if you are going to populate the loop with the data from the query then counting before the query is a waste of time and could be incorrect to (say a row is inserted between the count and select) just count the number of returned rows from the data query,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not call your `A` method inside the condition of the `for` loop - it will be executed on every iteration.

```
int count = A();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv = ...
}

public int A()
{
  ...
  using ( ...
    using ( ...
    {
      ...
      return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: good advice but you gloss over that you changed the return type of `A()` which is the actual change you made that's fixing his issue

Answer (score 2):

In this case, simply make `A()` return `int` instead of `void`:

```
public int A() {
    int count = 0;
    //do db stuff
    return count;
}
```

Then in your loop:

```
int shipCount = A();

for (int i = 0; i < shipCount; i++) {
    //make div
}
```

Comment: "cleaner"? it will be a disaster if he doesn't.

Comment: @Igor I saw your edit - I didn't know that! I'll remove that bit

Comment: @Igor Disaster is putting it a bit strongly, massively inefficient though i could agree with

Answer (score 1):

Too many things to say ^^'
First if you need to display info of the element in your table AlgSchipInfo, just select these data an after you will have the count in the datatable or anything else like an ORM.

When you get your datatable from the DB, bind it to a repeator or another compenent to list your items. It will bee more efficient than do it from scratch IMAO.

If you have more specific question you're welcome ;)